# Can't vote to close what was closed then reopened

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, closed-questions

Scenario....

Poor or unclear question is voted to close.. it gets closed.

User edits question to a more suitable form and question is reopened.

Through comments, it's clear the question is off topic anyway and should be closed.

I can't vote to close after a question has been reopened. 
**Shouldn't close votes be cleared if the question is reopened?**

Example: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26305/unexpected-transparencies-when-exporting-vector-to-png-in-illustrator

Originally it was just completely unclear, and closed as such. Now, it's off-topic as it's clearly a tech support issue based upon the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is done by design. From [**SO meta**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140723/after-voting-to-close-delete-and-reopen-i-cant-cast-a-close-vote):

Yes - this is correct behavior (AKA [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)) - as stated on the privileges page for [Cast close and reopen votes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions) -

> Questions can go through multiple close and reopen cycles, but each
>   individual user may only vote once in each direction in the cycle.

Because you have voted previously, you can't vote again. In this case, I think the best option is to flag for moderation.

Comment: I see the problem. Some of this can be helped if people give the asker a little time to clarify. Maybe be a little less triggerhappy in closing?

Comment: @boblet Well, because Close votes put the question On Hold, I think it can be 'educating' to the [new] OP to see the notification explaining why it needs some re-work. To be honest, I wasn't aware of this until Scott mentioned it, I thought close votes were sort of unlimited. I imagine it's a way of saving resources, although there are cases, like this one, when there might be necessary to close again. But at the same time, it can be closed by different users (which sounds more democratic?)

Comment: Yes, I see the problem, and I see how it was made. I do find the vote-to-close as an educating tool a little harsh for the first-timers. I know I would have fled. I know it can get annoying after reading seven badly worded, irrelevant questions, and voting to close is very tempting. Maybe because there aren´t hundreds of moderators and "privileged" users here, this "cannot vote to close something that was reopened" becomes a bother. I think Scott is right in that this is a bit silly, I would like to see it changed. But I still think holding back on the close-vote is currently the only way?

Comment: @boblet I actually find downvotes harsher, but it might be just me. That's why I'd rather close than downvote, because downvotes can't be purged if a question is edited and re-opened.

Comment: Fair enough. :) Seems odd, but I can see the need to eliminate merry-go-round issues.